# Java Swing: ¿Cómo hacer que un Scroll Pane se desplace automáticamente cuando un control recibe el enfoque?

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy escribiendo una app en Netbeans, y funciona (hasta ahora) bastante bien. Una de las cosas que estoy haciendo es poner un `JScrollPane` con un `JPanel` dentro para colocar mis controles (`JLabel`s, `JTextField`s, etcétera).

El problema que tengo es que a la hora que un control que no está visible (por estar "más abajo" o "más arriba" de lo que el Scroll Pane muestra), no puedo hacer que el Scroll Pane se desplace automáticamente para mostrar el control.

En esto estoy completamente perdido. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que el problema es al enfocar un elemento programaticamente o desplazarte con el teclado a través de ellos. Para ello necesitas un [`KeyboardFocusManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/KeyboardFocusManager.html) escuchando al evento `focusOwner`

Parte importante del código: (comentarios en el texto)

```
KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addPropertyChangeListener("focusOwner", new PropertyChangeListener() {
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        // ignoramos todo lo que no sea un componente
        if (!(evt.getNewValue() instanceof JComponent)) {
            return;
        }
        // cojemos el elemento, miramos que este en el contenedor 
        JComponent elementoEnfocado = (JComponent) evt.getNewValue();
        if (contenedor.isAncestorOf(elementoEnfocado)) {
            // y si es candidato, "enfocamos" el contenedor a la altura del elemento
            contenedor.scrollRectToVisible(elementoEnfocado.getBounds());
            System.out.println("Vamos al "+ elementoEnfocado.getName());
        }
    }
});
```

---

**CÓDIGO:**
Puedes encontrar un ejemplo completo y funcional [**en este proyecto de ideone**](https://ideone.com/E1NO3N) aunque deberás copiarlo y ejecutarlo en local ya que online no dispone de motor `Swing`.

---

- FUENTES [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615958/java-gui-how-to-set-focus-on-jbutton-in-jpanel-on-jframe), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8245328/how-do-i-make-jscrollpane-scroll-to-follow-input-focus)
- Si tienes dudas, [sílbame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QO7KYyDSkXA) `:)`.